# Цикл / Поиск количества делителей числа

Tags: python-3.x

Есть задача.
На вход программе подается натуральное число n. Напишите программу, которая вычисляет сумму всех его делителей.

Входные данные
На вход программе подается натуральное число n.

Выходные данные
Программа должна вывести единственное число в соответствии с условием задачи.

Написал вот такой кода

```
x = int(input())
counter = 0
for i in range(1, x + 1):
    if x % i == 0:
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Но выводит не верно, не то кол-во делителей. Должно быть 18 делителей, а у мееня получается 4. В чем ошибка ???

Comment: Добро пожаловать! У какого числа 18 делителей?

Comment: Ну вы же нигде не считаете сумму, а только количество. У вас даже имя переменной намекает на свою суть. Ну и да, для каких входных данных вы ожидаете обозначенный результат тоже неплохо было бы указать!

Comment: ошибка в том, что перепутал сумму делителей с их количеством

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно вывести количество делителей, сами делители, или их сумму?

```
def printDivisors(n):
    count = 0
    summ = 0
    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        if (n % i == 0):
            print("{} - делитель числа {}".format(i, n))
            count += 1
            summ += i
        i += 1
    print("Количество делителей числа {} = {}".format(n, count))
    print("Сумма делителей числа {} = {}".format(n, summ))
```

Comment: Всё хорошо, только зачем вы вместо `for i in range(1, x + 1):` сделали через `while` - это три строки кода вместо одной. И `format` уже давно никто не использует, используйте лучше `f-строки`.